# Saving real time data in Android application to access later

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, streaming, real-time

I am currently streaming information in the form of a String from an Arduino to an Android application via Bluetooth. My application currently just displays the data on a series of progress bars as the values come in. I would like to store the data as it comes in to be viewed later but am unsure as to how to achieve this.

I have a BluetoothActionListener which runs when new data is available. This is called up to 20 times per second so I am worried as to whether adding a memory save to a file within this function will have an effect on its performance.

The data arrives as a string via bluetooth and I would like to be able to store the entire session's worth of data (upto 10mins) in the same file on a different line. A simple text file with a timestamp on each line is sufficient.

Would using a internal/external memory write cause my foreground visuals to slow down or even become unresponsive, as each new string arriving causes each of the progress bars to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At twenty times a second?  Probably not.  Just keep the file open rather than closing it, and flush it every few writes.